# Sony RX100M4 viewfinder keeps popping up in my pocket turning the camera on

Tags: sony, sony-rx100

I have a nice 5 month old Sony RX100M4 which I bought for having an "in-pocket" alternative to my Canon 70D.  It takes amazing pictures but when I have it in my pocket it keeps turning on (extending the lens).  As the viewfinder is popped up every time and I never use it, my guess is that the viewfinders physical lock for some reason is unlocked and pops up.

I would like to avoid this.  Is this a well-known problem with a common easy solution (like a piece of tape over the viewfinder) or is it my camera and I should look into a warranty repair?

Comment: I gave up on this and used a bit of duct tape to keep the viewfinder down.   I like this camera but it certainly has personality.

Answer (score 1):

Authorized service would be the most certain way to determine if it is a defect. If the camera is under warranty, a warranty claim will help the manufacturer correct the manufacture/design issue if one exists.